# Composite graphics with Row, Column, data aggregation and layout control

Tags: graphics, functional-style

This chromogram shown [here](http://statigrafix.com/projects/pace/dataviz/CHROMO.EMR.n119.pdf)
represents data (mouse activity patterns during visits) for ~20 physicians in a study, each of which may have a variable number of visits in the study (physicians are color coded; also the last 2 digits in the XXX-YY). So each row represents one visit.

Row and Column are used to layout the graphical elements including the XXX-YY annotation (the arrow is due to using Rule in key-value pairs). The query looks something like this:

```
Column[#,ItemSize->90]&@  PACE[VISITS] /. 
      v_String:>Row@{PROVIDERCOLOR@v ->  Graphics[VGr[v/.PACE[V1]],ChromoGrOptions]}
```

Taking the resulting expression as argument, how can the spacing be adjusted so that there is more space between distinct physicians' data?

A method I want to avoid, if possible, is to restructure the data and call `Column` separately perhaps with different padding parameters. Though perhaps it's possible to apply `Map` or `Thread` or combinations, to effect that rewrite.

Thoughts?

Comment: I assume you tried `Spacings` option for `Column` to control horizontal and vertical spacings of items? E.g. `Table[Table[Column[{1, 22, 333}, Spacings -> {h, v}, 
   Frame -> True], {h, {1, 3, 5}}], {v, {1, 3, 5}}]`

Comment: @kguler, the data does contains information that could be used to parametrize Spacing option. The questions are (1) how to pattern match Spacing parameters from the data; (2) how to effect that tranformation without changing the query that includes calls to Row and Column?

Answer (score 3):

This is more an idea than an answer.

That kind of graphical output seems ideal for multi cell output. This way, if the output is very long, *Mathematica* handles the page breaks for you (in case you need to print or generate a PDF report).

Try this:

```
CellPrint /@ Table[Graphics[{Gray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 1}]}], {10}]
```

[image: multi cell output]

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of CellPrint